# ScrollView not scrolling in React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

I just started learning how to use React Native and wanted to learn as I went while creating a simple project, I'm trying to create a ScrollView of card items but I can't seem to get it to scroll. I've been looking around stack overflow trying the solutions like flex:1 but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is my code

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flex:1}}>
          <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
            <View style={{flex:0.5}}> 
              <View style={styles.card}><Text>Test</Text></View>
              <View style={styles.card}><Text>Test2</Text></View>
              <View style={styles.card}><Text>Test3</Text></View>
              <View style={styles.card}><Text>Test4</Text></View>
              <View style={styles.card}><Text>Test5</Text></View>
              <View style={styles.card}><Text>Test6</Text></View>
              <View style={styles.card}><Text>Test7</Text></View>
            </View>
            <View style={{flex:0.5}}> 
              <View style={styles.card}><Text>Testi</Text></View>
              <View style={styles.card}><Text>Testii</Text></View>
              <View style={styles.card}><Text>Testiii</Text></View>
              <View style={styles.card}><Text>Testiv</Text></View>
              <View style={styles.card}><Text>Testv</Text></View>
              <View style={styles.card}><Text>Testvi</Text></View>
              <View style={styles.card}><Text>Testvii</Text></View>
            </View>
          </View>
</ScrollView>
```

My CSS :

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  card:
  {
    height:'20%',
    margin:10,
    borderWidth:1,
    borderColor:'#000',
    borderStyle:'solid',
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given flex 0.5 to both of the children views,

So here make sure that contents don't have fixed size in flex.

You can remove this 0.5 flex and give instead `width:'50%'` also remove `flex:1` which is causing your scroll view to utilizing only viewable height.

```
<ScrollView>
          <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
            <View style={{width:"50%"}}> 
              <View style={styles.card}><Text>Test</Text></View>
              <View style={styles.card}><Text>Test2</Text></View>
              <View style={styles.card}><Text>Test3</Text></View>
              <View style={styles.card}><Text>Test4</Text></View>
              <View style={styles.card}><Text>Test5</Text></View>
              <View style={styles.card}><Text>Test6</Text></View>
              <View style={styles.card}><Text>Test7</Text></View>
            </View>
            <View style={{width:"50%"}}> 
              <View style={styles.card}><Text>Testi</Text></View>
              <View style={styles.card}><Text>Testii</Text></View>
              <View style={styles.card}><Text>Testiii</Text></View>
              <View style={styles.card}><Text>Testiv</Text></View>
              <View style={styles.card}><Text>Testv</Text></View>
              <View style={styles.card}><Text>Testvi</Text></View>
              <View style={styles.card}><Text>Testvii</Text></View>
            </View>
          </View>
</ScrollView>
```

**EDIT:** also give height to card fixed instead of percentage because the view doesn't know what total size is so it cant calculate 20% exactly

see working eg. https://snack.expo.io/@jdgalani6297/scrolling-issue

Comment: This solved my problem but I just wanted to further clarify is it because flex property is making my parent view's height fixed to the max height of the screen thus not allowing it to scroll?

Comment: you got it. That's the cause

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
            <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1 }}>
                    <View style={{ flex: 0.5 }}>
                        <View style={styles.card}><Text>Test</Text></View>
                        <View style={styles.card}><Text>Test2</Text></View>
                        <View style={styles.card}><Text>Test3</Text></View>
                        <View style={styles.card}><Text>Test4</Text></View>
                        <View style={styles.card}><Text>Test5</Text></View>
                        <View style={styles.card}><Text>Test6</Text></View>
                        <View style={styles.card}><Text>Test7</Text></View>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ flex: 0.5 }}>
                        <View style={styles.card}><Text>Testi</Text></View>
                        <View style={styles.card}><Text>Testii</Text></View>
                        <View style={styles.card}><Text>Testiii</Text></View>
                        <View style={styles.card}><Text>Testiv</Text></View>
                        <View style={styles.card}><Text>Testv</Text></View>
                        <View style={styles.card}><Text>Testvi</Text></View>
                        <View style={styles.card}><Text>Testvii</Text></View>
                    </View>

                </View>
            </ScrollView>
```

Card CSS:

**NOTE** :  Don't forget to import `Dimensions`

```
      card: {
            height: (Dimensions.get('window').height * 0.20),
            margin: 10,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: '#000',
            borderStyle: 'solid',
        }
```

Comment: I gave a vote just for the Dimensions tip but this did not solve my problem, thank you anyways.